# Is there alternatives for underscore 'extend' method for Node Js for deep cloning?

Tags: jquery, node.js, underscore.js

I need to make deep cloning an objects in Node.js. I'm using `_.extend` at now but according [this](http://techiella.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/underscore-js-extend-vs-jquery-extend/) it might get a problems due shallow copying of nested objects. I need to have deep cloning most like as `jQuery.extend`. So my question is there are any Node.js modules (or native ones) for deep object cloning?

Comment: What do you need this for? How do your circular references look?

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/lodash/lodash

has deep clone method which i think is what you want :)

```
var cloneOfDeepNestedObject _.cloneDeep(deepNestedObject);
```

http://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep

provides a one for one replacement for underscore with some additinoal methods

seems stable used it a few times, seems to be equivalent, claims to be faster too